# How many transistors do modern (2020) sattellite SPUs have?

Tags: electronics

After reading about Moore's law and the amount of transistors of CPUs on Earth, I learned that currently there are chips out there with roughly 50 billion transistors:

[image: Moore's Law: visualisation of the number of transistors on CPU's.]
(Image source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transistor%20count&oldid=1029095489))

However, the application of space technology is often a bit more conservative, as it often requires proven technology.

Hence, I was wondering how many transistors are there in typical 2020 satellite bus CPUs*? And what does More's law look like applied to satellite bus CPUs* transistors only?

I found two data points:

- the RAD750 has 10.4 million transistors. It was first introduced in 2000 and flew through space for the first time in 2005 according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAD750).
- the 603e has a transistor count of [2.6 million](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC603EEC.pdf), and [is used by Honeywell as in satellites](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/us/en/learn/products/space/spacecraft-on-board-computer).

Yet I did not find any proof of satellites with CPUs with a number of transistors that is in the order of billions.

### * Notes

In response to the comments:

1. I would like to narrow the question down to the number of transistors in the CPU of the satellite, ignoring transistors in other locations.
2. I would like to explicitly narrow down the question to satellite bus CPUs that are used to maintain the spacecraft's basic operation (e.g. attitude control, power and thermal maintenance, station keeping maneuvers, etc.).
3. Note 2 implies the question ignores application-specific processors on the payload side (for example: synthetic aperture radar signal processors with mixed CPU/DSP/FPGA).

Comment: Check out aerospace.honeywell.com - they make space qualified microelectronics.

Comment: I think this is a great question! Would you like answers to consider *application-specific processors* on the payload side (just for example synthetic aperture radar signal processors with mixed CPU/DSP/FPGA) as well, or just the satellite bus CPU used to maintain the spacecraft's basic operation (e.g. attitude control, power and thermal maintenance, station keeping maneuvers, etc.)?

Comment: Different but related: [SAR image processing](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20231/12102) and [What makes Insight's RAD750 processor so radiation resistant? (compared to 1998 iMac's PowerPC 750)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50470/12102) and [What computer and software is used by the Falcon 9?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9243/12102) (this is of course not a "satellite" but an orbiting Dragon capsule might be considered one by some)

Comment: This wouldn't count either: [HPE's demo HPC system; why choose optical and not copper interconnects because of magnetic fields and radiation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22653/12102)